# Ubuntu website crashing - domain can't resolve to IP address when Apache is running

Tags: 20.04, apache2, dns

I have a website on Ubuntu VPS server. Set DNS and all thing was working for a month or so just fine now it suddenly crash. I checked for Apache service it says it's active and running on Ubuntu just fine. VPN is also running, so is Hestia control panel. However ping does not work, says can't find domain - can't resolve domain to IP. So where is the problem? Is the problem with DNS zones? They are set, thing worked for about a month. Or domain provider has problem? Where I start fixing things?

Thanks, B

Comment: Sounds like the DNS provider isn't working right.  Try to find out what IP address you have for the VPS and then see if the website from whatever DDNS you are using matches.  I wouldn't really know where to start because you haven't stated if your VPS is static IP or dynamic IP also if you are using a DDNS service like no-ip.com.

Comment: static IP. no no-ip.com

Comment: Can you ping the static IP?  If so, you need to check with whatever company is supplying your hostname.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing" if it's still "running fine"?

Comment: can't ping - thats the problem, says cant find IP by hostname

Comment: Pinging the hostname vs pinging the static IP address are two different things.  Don't ping by hostname but instead by the actual IP like `ping 72.100.26.XXX` or whatever the IP address is that they assigned you.  We cannot get that info for you, you will need to get that from your VPS service or whoever assigned you the static IP.